# Write date and time into LOG file in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, logfile

I would like to write into my LOG file the current date and time :

```
$logFileName = 'file://c:\MYLOG.log'; // /var/logs/file.log
$logContent = "Running through the function".PHP_EOL;
$date = (new DateTime('NOW'))->format("y:m:d h:i:s");
if ($handle = fopen($logFileName, 'a')) 
{
  fwrite($handle, $date);
  fwrite($handle, PHP_EOL);
  fwrite($handle, $logContent);
  fwrite($handle, PHP_EOL);
  fwrite($handle, $cmdWindows);
  fwrite($handle, PHP_EOL);
  fwrite($handle, $params);
  fwrite($handle, PHP_EOL);
 }
 fclose($handle);
```

When it is running through my method, I can see all my wanted information but not the date and the time.
Can you tell me where am I wrong please ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your datatime constructor now isn't necessary because it's default. And as for you answer you can't apply chaining on a constructor (before PHP 5.4) 
if you have PHP > 5.4 you can apply constructor chaining like this `(new Foo)->bar()`

Example below will definitly work:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date = $date->format("y:m:d h:i:s");
```